# Cannot manipulate css class based on index of ngFor. Angular5

Tags: carousel, angular5

I am facing a problem while trying to implement bootstrap carousel in angular 5. I have a list of images that are coming from a server and want to display the list of images in a carousel. For carousel to work properly I need to set active class in index 0 only. But I could not achieve this based on different instructions found online.

I am doing this to get the result but it does not work

```
<div class="carousel-inner" *ngFor="let relatedPhoto of relatedPhotos; index as i">

          <div class="carousel-item" **ng-class="{'active': i == 0}**">
              {{i == 0}}
            <img src="../../assets/images/{{relatedPhoto}}" width="100%" alt="Los Angeles">
          </div>
</div>
```

Any idea on this problem? I don't see any images in the browser.

Comment: can you try with `<img src="assets/images/{{relatedPhoto}}" width="100%" alt="Los Angeles">` as it will take the relative path itself.

Comment: Without ng-class i can see image. There is no problem.

Comment: I have used `[ngClass]="stringExp|arrayExp|objExp"` this in angular 4.
https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass
or `ngStyle`
https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/

Comment: you should use [ngClass]="{'active':i==0}"

Comment: Solved the problem with [ngClass]. Thank you so much